# I am tying to use an event, but it doesnt register because the curser is still in the entry field (tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

I have an entry field in my window and I want to type someting in the entry field,
press enter, and something happends, but it doesnt work because the curser is still in the entry field when I press enter after I typed someting

here is the code ive been using oversimpified (the for this question non important parts left out)

```
from tkinter import *    
     
def some_func():
    #other code I want to happen when I press enter


root = Tk()


entry_one_root = Entry(root).place(x=0, y=0)







root.mainloop()
```

Is there a way to fix that?
thx for your help

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add a [mre].

Comment: Where do you expect the cursor to go? Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for ?

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
entry = tk.Entry(tk.root)

def some_func():
    ...

# Bind enter key on entry to some_func
entry.bind("<Enter>", lambda event: some_func())
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I edited the question so the code is in it, maybee you can help now :)

Comment: I changed my answer a bit, it should work. Tell me if it doesn't.